# Differentiate $5^{x \cos x}$

Tags: calculus

How do I differentiate $5^{x \cos x}$? From my book, it should be implicit differentiation, but how do I start?

If I let $u = x \cos x$, then I get

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dY}{dX} &=& u \cdot 5^{u - 1} \cdot \frac{du}{dX}
\\ &=& x \cdot \cos x \cdot 5^{x \cos x-1} \cdot (\cos x-x \sin x)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I don't suppose I did it right... The correct answer is

$$ \ln5 \cdot 5^{x \cos x}\cdot (\cos x-x \sin x) .$$

Comment: We have $5=e^{\ln 5}$. So our function is $e^{(\ln 5)(x\cos x)}$. Now use the Chain Rule. Or else let $y=5^{x\ln x}$. Then $\ln y=(x\ln x)(\ln 5)$. Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, using implicit differentiation for the left-hand side.

Comment: What happens if you take the logarithm?

Comment: Ah ... 1 thing I dont get is how is $5=e^{ln5}$. Also how did you convert $xcosx \rightarrow x ln x$

Comment: @jiewmang: The logarithm is the inverse of the exponential function, so $\exp\ln x=\ln\exp x=x$. I think André made an error when he spoke of $x\ln x$, I think he meant $x\cos x$.

Comment: Oh I think I am getting you, the part about inverse ... but what bothers me is I could explain the 2nd part, $ln(e^x)=xlog_e e=x$, but I can't derive x from $e^{lnx}$. Apart from "understanding" $\ln{x}$ and $e^x$ are inverse

Comment: jiewmeng: For $x>0$ (in real numbers the logarithm isn't defined for $x\le0$ anyway), we can write $x=e^w$ for some $w$, in which case $$\large e^{\ln x}=e^{\ln e^w}=e^w=x.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that the derivative of $5^u$ (with respect to $u$) is **not** $u5^{u-1}$; this isn't $u$ to a power but rather a base to the power of $u$. The usual route is with André's advice: write the function as an exponential, so $5^{x\cos x}=(e^{\ln5})^{x\cos x}=\exp(\ln5\cdot x\cos x)$. Here we use the fact that the natural logarithm and exponential functions are inverse functions of each other, so $\exp\ln a=\ln\exp a=a $.

Now apply the chain rule, and remember the exponential function is its own derivative.

Comment: I wonder why no one mentioned the *rule*:$\frac{d}{dx}a^{x}=a^x.\ln a$ for $a>0$.

Comment: @Swapan: I personally find it more convenient to remember that the natural exponential function is its own derivative, and then use the chain-rule subsequently...

Comment: @Swapan: Because the rule is derived first by making $a^x$ into $\exp(x \ln a)$ and then applying the chain rule, as here. When learning theory one shouldn't use rules before one knows why they work...

Comment: @J.M. and anon: My point was just a *mention*...may be then how it works or in reverse order. Once, simplified (and probably knowing *how it works*), I always found it is useful to use the *ready-made rule*;, e.g., to use Binomial Theorem to expand $(a+b)^8$ than multiplying 8 times or in this case using the original definition of derivative as limits :)